# count the matching characters between two inputs given by user

Tags: python, count, match

How do i get this python output? counting matches and mismatches

String1: aaabbbccc     #aaabbbccc is user input
String2: aabbbcccc     #aabbbcccc is user input

Matches: ?
MisMatches: ?
String1: aaAbbBccc  #mismatches are capitalize
String2: aaBbbCccc

Comment: Will the number of characters be the same?

Comment: user can input as much as they want.

Comment: @SamyShrestha What would be expected output if the inputs are "abcd" and "abcdefghijklmnop"?

Comment: i want to learn this.. i have no idea for counting matches and mismatches.. so just tried searching in python library. but didnt find anything.

Comment: Hint: `zip`, or possibly `itertools.izip_longest` ...

Comment: @mgilson must use `itertools.izip_longest`

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework (that you haven't tired to complete yourself), much like your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873701/how-to-write-a-python-program-to-get-minimum-maximum-and-average-by-user-input

Comment: @AvinashRaj of course you don't *have* to.

Comment: not homework actually... it's just a project kind of thing...
@avinash thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have gotten the string from a file or user input, what about:

```
import itertools

s1 = 'aaabbbccc'
s2 = 'aabbbcccc'

# This will only consider n characters, where n = min(len(s1), len(s2))
match_indices = [i for (i,(c1, c2)) in enumerate(itertools.izip(s1, s2)) if c1 == c2]
num_matches   = len(match_indices)
num_misses    = min(len(s1), len(s2)) - num_matches

print("Matches:    %d" % num_matches)
print("Mismatches: %d" % num_misses)
print("String 1:   %s" % ''.join(c if i in match_indices else c.upper() for (i,c) in enumerate(s1)))
print("String 2:   %s" % ''.join(c if i in match_indices else c.upper() for (i,c) in enumerate(s2)))
```

Output:

```
Matches:    7
Mismatches: 2
String 1:   aaAbbBccc
String 1:   aaBbbCccc
```

If you wanted to count strings of uneven length (where extra characters counted as misses), you could change:

```
num_misses  = min(len(s1), len(s2)) - num_matches
# to
num_misses  = max(len(s1), len(s2)) - num_matches
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
s1 = 'aaabbbccc'
s2 = 'aabbbcccc'
print "Matches:", sum( c1==c2 for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2) )
print "Mismatches:", sum( c1!=c2 for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2) )
print "String 1:", ''.join( c1 if c1==c2 else c1.upper() for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2) )
print "String 2:", ''.join( c2 if c1==c2 else c2.upper() for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2) )
```

This produces:

```
Matches: 7
Mismatches: 2
String 1: aaAbbBccc
String 2: aaBbbCccc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

```
>>> s1 = 'aaabbbccc'
>>> s2 = 'aabbbcccc'
>>> match = 0
>>> mismatch = 0
>>> for i,j in itertools.izip_longest(s1,s2):
        if i == j:
            match += 1
        else:
            mismatch +=1
```

In python3 use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of `itertools.izip_longest`.
If you want to consider `a` and `A` as a match, then change  the if condition to,

```
if i.lower() == j.lower():
```

Finally get the match and mismatch count from the variables `match` and `mismatch` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    index = 0
    for letter in String1:
        if String1[index] != String2[index]:
            mismatches +=1
    index += 1
print "Matches:" + (len(String1)-mismatches)
print "Mismatches:" + mismatches
```

Comment: Is there a loop-type line you omitted?

Comment: actually it's like after entering the user input. the program asks for 
a(add indel)
d(delete indel)
s(score)
q(quit): s 
when 's' is entered then, it gives the required information as output

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>s= list('aaabbbccc')
>>>s1=list('aabbbcccc')
>>>match=0
>>>mismatch=0
>>>for i in range(0,len(s)):
...     if(s[i]==s1[i]):
...             match+=1
...     else:
...             mismatch+=1
...             s[i]=s[i].upper()
...             s1[i]=s1[i].upper()
>>>print 'Matches:'+ str(match)
>>>print 'MisMatches:'+str(mismatch)
>>>print 'String 1:' +''.join(s)
>>>print 'String 2:' +''.join(s1)
```